# How to access object according to Key Javascript in messages.json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, internationalization

Object is

```
var dict = {};
  function loadDict() {
  var lang = (getCookieVal("lang") || "en");
  $.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: "GET",
    url: "/lang/"+lang + ".json",
    success: function (msg) {
      dict = msg;
      sessionStorage.setItem(lang + 'Data', JSON.stringify(dict));
    }
  });

}
```

`console.log (dict);` will give you

```
tabLanding:{message: "Landing"}
tabSetup:{message: "Setup"}
__proto__:Object
```

on my html:

```
<li class="tab_setup"><a href="#" i18n="tabSetup"></a></li>
```

i really do not know how to use javascript to make html shows landing according to key in json file `tabLanding`

here is my full code javasScript

```
  var dict = {};
var systemLang = navigator.language.toLowerCase().slice(0,2);
$(function () {
  registerWords();
  switch(getCookieVal("lang")) {
    case "en" :
      setLanguage("en");
      break
    case "zh" :
      setLanguage("zh");
      break
    default:
      setLanguage(systemLang);
  }
  console.log (dict);
  console.log (dict.tabLanding.message);

// 切换语言事件
  $("#enBtn").bind("click", function () {
    setLanguage("en");
  });

  $("#zhBtn").bind("click", function () {
    setLanguage("zh");
  });

  // $("#applyBtn").bind("click", function () {
  //   alert(__tr("a translation test!"));
  // });
});

function setLanguage(lang) {
  setCookie("lang=" + lang + "; path=/;");
  translate(lang);
}

function getCookieVal(name) {
  var items = document.cookie.split(";");
  for (var i in items) {
    var cookie = $.trim(items[i]);
    var eqIdx = cookie.indexOf("=");
    var key = cookie.substring(0, eqIdx);
    if (name == $.trim(key)) {
      return $.trim(cookie.substring(eqIdx + 1));
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function setCookie(cookie) {
  var Days = 30; //此 cookie 将被保存 30 天
  var exp = new Date(); //new Date("December 31, 9998");
  exp.setTime(exp.getTime() + Days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  document.cookie = cookie+ ";expires=" + exp.toGMTString();
}

function translate(lang) {
  if(sessionStorage.getItem(lang + "Data") != null){
    dict = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(lang + "Data"));
  }else{
    loadDict();
  }

  $("[i18n]").each(function () {
    switch (this.tagName.toLowerCase()) {
      case "input":
        $(this).val(__tr($(this).attr("i18n")));
        break;
      default:
        $(this).text(__tr($(this).attr("i18n")));
    }
  });
}

function __tr(src) {
  return (dict[src] || src);
}

function loadDict() {
  var lang = (getCookieVal("lang") || "en");
  $.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: "GET",
    url: "/lang/"+lang + ".json",
    success: function (msg) {
      dict = msg;
      sessionStorage.setItem(lang + 'Data', JSON.stringify(dict));
    }
  });

}
// 遍历所有lang属性的标签赋值
function registerWords() {

    $('[i18n]:not(.i18n-replaced').each(function() {
        var element = $(this);

        element.html(translate(element.attr('i18n')));

        element.addClass('i18n-replaced');

  });
}
```

this now shows 【object Object】 rather than landing..................

Comment: Have you tried like this `console.log(dict.tabLanding.message);`

Answer (score 0):

Use `.html()` in jQuery on the element that you want to add "landing" to. This will put whatever is inside the brackets between the tags of the element you are targetting.

I'm guessing you want to add "landing" inside the anchor tags:

`<li class="tab_setup"><a href="#" i18n="tabSetup"></a></li>`

You can also use `dict.tabLanding.message` to accesses "landing" from your dictionary.

So, if you wish to do this you can do the following:

`$('.tab_setup').find('a').html(dict.tabLanding.message)`

So, you can use this like so:

```
var dict = {};
  function loadDict() {
  var lang = (getCookieVal("lang") || "en");
  $.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: "GET",
    url: "/lang/"+lang + ".json",
    success: function (msg) {
      dict = msg;
      sessionStorage.setItem(lang + 'Data', JSON.stringify(dict));
      $('.tab_setup').find('a').html(dict.tabLanding.message); // Add "landing" to anchor tag inside the element with the class tab_setup
    }
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this way with [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML). Also see how to access nested objects in javascript here https://dev.to/flexdinesh/accessing-nested-objects-in-javascript--9m4

```js
var dict = {tabLanding:{message: "Landing"}}
var anchor = document.querySelector('li a');
anchor.innerHTML = dict.tabLanding.message;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<li class="tab_setup"><a href="#" i18n="tabSetup"></a></li>
</body>
</html>
```